# Number from input AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wan't to show in console.log `$scope.value` from input in which I have chosen the number, after click.

My code :

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th >Name
                            <th >System
                            </th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="n in data">
                            <td style ="word-break:break-all;">{{n.name}}</td>

                            <td style="width:35px;">{{n.system}}</td>
                            <td><input class="form-control input-sm" type="number" name="input" ng-model="value"
                                       min="0" max="100" style="width:55px;">
                                </td>

                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <button ng-click="postapi()">Value</button>
```

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/g1t4pludTTIAJYKTToCK?p=preview

Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to bind all elements in data to `value` instead binding each element to it's own value like `ng-model="n.value"` instead `ng-model="value"`? With your approach you will have the same value for all items in `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the `value` that you define inside the ng-repeat because the ng-repeat create it's own scope. And what i know is that you can't access a child scope from a parent scope.

It will be better if you change `ng-model="value"` to `ng-model="n.value"`. Then you can access the value over the object